# Reading multiple files from a directory, R

Tags: r

I am having difficulty with one step in my code to read in a folder of text files and convert it to a dtm.  The problem is that, for some reason, my computer is only able to intermittently establish a connection with the text files in the directory.  The error that returns is:

```
Error in file(con, "r") : cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(con, "r") :
  cannot open file '[file name]': No such file or directory
```

However, I can easily open these files in any text editor, as well as in python.  Any ideas why I might be able to establish the connection sometimes and not others?  My code is below:

```
files <- as.character(list.files(path="[file path]"))
readLines(files[1])  #here is where the error occurs, for example
n <- length(files) #this is my loop
subtitles <- character(n)
subtitle <- character(1)

for (i in 1:n){
   subtitle <- as.character(readLines(files[i]))
   subtitle <- iconv(subtitle, to="UTF8")
   subtitle <-  tolower(subtitle)
   subtitle <- as.character(paste(subtitle, collapse=" "))
   subtitles[i] <- subtitle[1]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

`List.files`only gives you the file names, not file names with full path. Try

```
files <- as.character(list.files(path="[file path]"))
readLines(paste("[file path]",.Platform$file.sep,files[1],sep=""))
```

Comment: or just use `list.files` with `full.names = TRUE`.

Comment: oh wow. thanks. this is just a working directory problem. Sorry for the waste of time!

Answer (score 1):

```
directory <- "C://temp"  ## for example
filenames <- list.files(directory, pattern = "*.*", full.names = TRUE)
```

Comment: Very helpful for me. Thanks so much +1